# "Debugging" installed fonts. Which font is mapped to which serie/shape?

Tags: fonts, pdftex, fontspec, opentype, truetype

I installed some new fonts using autoinst.

Now I have a problem finding back the font family/shape/serie which belongs to my bold font which I believe I installed it.

After I did:

```
\usefont{T1}{<my font>}{b}{n}
```

I got:

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T1/<my font>/b/n' undefined
(Font)  using `T1/<my font>/m/n' instead on input line 34.
```

So to 'debug' this issue I have 1 question:

How can I (automatically or  manual) collect the following information: a list of all recognized fonts with:

font family, font series, font shape.

Does there a package exist, to dump this information to the console when (Pdf)Latex runs?

Even nicer: is it possible create a Latex A4 PDF output which contains all font information, and some sample text?

So a package or construct which outputs:

```
\documentclass....
<for font in allFont>
 <for serie in font>
   <for shape in font>
      Font: <font>, Serie: <serie>, Shape: <shape>
      \usefont{T1}{<font>}{<serie>}{<shape>}
      Demo text in this font
```

Tx

Comment: Not an answer, but try `bx` instead of `b`. It may not work, but it is worth trying before investigating further. This is one reason I don't like `autoinst`. It spews files everywhere and it is very difficult to (1) control and (2) track.

Comment: OK, I found out I needed to use serie 'mb'  to get the right font selected. However, I still want to know how I can find this faster than just a bit trail and error.

Comment: For specific font families, you can read the `.fd` files.